# PyInstaller creates an exe file, it works for the menu but it doesn't work for the actual program

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, curses

Okay so I'm using pyinstaller to create an exe file for my python project to run, but when I run it, the exe file will open up my menu, and it will work perfectly fine, but when I select an option, it will clear the screen and then close the program. The program works perfectly well when run from command line. Below is the menu that I using pyinstaller on.

```
from pick import pick
import subprocess

def select_difficulty():
    title = "Welcome to LowKeyBored's implementation of Typing Test (Rev 0)!"+'\nSelect difficulty'
    options = ['Easy','Medium','Hard']
    option, index = pick(options, title)
    return option

def set_difficulty():
    diff_args = ['-v']
    difficulty = select_difficulty()
    if difficulty == 'Easy':
        diff_args.append('easy')
    elif difficulty == 'Medium':
        diff_args.append('medium')
    else:
        diff_args.append('hard')
    return diff_args

def main():
    diff_args = set_difficulty()
    launch_args = ['python3','runner.py']+diff_args
    subprocess.run(launch_args)

main()
```

runner .py

```
import typing_test
typing_test.main()
```

typingtest.py

```
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 Emil Lynegaard
Distributed under the MIT software license, see the
accompanying LICENSE.md or https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

Minimal 10fastfingers like typing game for Python2/3 with ncurses.
Supports vocab files as arguments, as well as adjustable
word length, game time and word frequency (if using sorted vocab).
"""
import argparse
import time
import random
import curses
import textwrap
import os

# Robust path to default vocabulary, which is based on word frequency
# from CNN and DailyMail articles.
VOCAB_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data", "vocab")

# Used for WPM calculation
CHARS_PER_WORD = 5

# Amount of words to store, for showing several future words
# Should generally be equal to at least two lines worth of words
QUEUE_SIZE = 30

# Maximum amount of characters to be displayed in a single row
MAX_WIDTH = 80

# pylint: disable=too-many-instance-attributes
class Game:
    """
    Class encapsulating the Game.
    Includes game stats, input management, game display.
    """

    CORRECT_COLOR = 1
    INCORRECT_COLOR = 2

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.word_generator = self._word_generator(args)
        self.game_time = args.game_time
        self.next_words = [self._get_word() for _ in range(QUEUE_SIZE)]
        self.typed = []
        self.correct = []
        self.incorrect = []
        self.input = ""

        self.display = args.display

        # if using 10ff display, we keep track of extra things
        if self.display == "10ff":
            self.offset = 0
            self.current_line = []
            self.next_line = []

    @staticmethod
    def _word_generator(args):
        words = []
        for line in open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data",args.vocab)):
            word = line.strip()
            if args.min_length <= len(word) <= args.max_length:
                words.append(word)

            if len(words) >= args.words:
                break
        
        if args.mode == "word":
            while True:
                yield random.choice(words)
        else:
            while True:
                yield from words

    def calculate_cpm(self, time_played):
        """Calculate CPM given time_played in seconds"""
        if time_played == 0:
            return 0

        correct_chars = len(" ".join(self.correct))
        cpm = 60 / time_played * correct_chars
        cpm = int(round(cpm))
        return cpm

    def calculate_wpm(self, time_played):
        """Calculate WPM given time_played in seconds"""
        cpm = self.calculate_cpm(time_played)
        wpm = cpm // CHARS_PER_WORD
        return wpm

    def _get_word(self):
        return next(self.word_generator)

    def _finish_word_event(self):
        target = self.next_words.pop(0)
        self.typed.append(self.input)
        if self.input == target:
            self.correct.append(target)
        else:
            self.incorrect.append(target)

        if self.display == "10ff":
            self.offset += 1

        self.next_words.append(self._get_word())
        self.input = ""

    @staticmethod
    def _get_line(words, max_chars):
        line = []
        chars = 0
        for word in words:
            length = len(word)
            # use +1 to account for added whitespace
            if chars + length + 1 > max_chars:
                break

            line.append(word)
            chars += length + 1

        return line

    def _progressive_display(self, stdscr, time_left):
        _height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
        width = min(width, MAX_WIDTH)

        stdscr.clear()
        wpm = self.calculate_wpm(self.game_time - time_left)
        stdscr.addstr("Time left: {:d}, WPM: {:d}\n".format(time_left, wpm)+", Difficulty Level: "+self.difficulty_level+"\n")

        line = self._get_line(self.next_words, width)
        target = " ".join(line)

        for idx, char in enumerate(self.input):
            target_char = target[idx]
            if target_char == char:
                stdscr.addstr(char, curses.color_pair(self.CORRECT_COLOR))
            else:
                stdscr.addstr(target_char, curses.color_pair(self.INCORRECT_COLOR))

        stdscr.addstr(target[len(self.input) : width - 1])
        stdscr.addstr("\n" + self.input, curses.A_UNDERLINE)
        stdscr.refresh()

    def _10ff_display(self, stdscr, time_left):
        _height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
        width = min(width, MAX_WIDTH)
        stdscr.clear()

        wpm = self.calculate_wpm(self.game_time - time_left)
        # stdscr.addstr("Time left: {:d}, WPM: {:d}".format(time_left, wpm)+", Difficulty Level: "+self.difficulty_level+"\n")
        stdscr.addstr("Time left: {:d}, WPM: {:d}".format(time_left, wpm)+"\n")

        # sets up initial lines
        if not self.current_line:
            self.current_line = self._get_line(self.next_words, width)
            cur_len = len(self.current_line)
            self.next_line = self._get_line(self.next_words[cur_len:], width)

        # if we finished the current line
        if self.offset >= len(self.current_line):
            self.current_line = self.next_line
            cur_len = len(self.current_line)
            self.next_line = self._get_line(self.next_words[cur_len:], width)
            self.offset = 0

        # color the words already typed on current line
        for i in range(self.offset):
            target = self.current_line[i]
            actual = self.typed[-(self.offset - i)]
            if actual == target:
                stdscr.addstr(target, curses.color_pair(self.CORRECT_COLOR))
            else:
                stdscr.addstr(target, curses.color_pair(self.INCORRECT_COLOR))

            stdscr.addstr(" ")

        stdscr.addstr(" ".join(self.current_line[self.offset :]))
        stdscr.addstr("\n" + " ".join(self.next_line))
        stdscr.addstr("\n" + self.input, curses.A_UNDERLINE)
        stdscr.refresh()

    def _update_display(self, stdscr, time_left):
        if self.display == "progressive":
            self._progressive_display(stdscr, time_left)
        elif self.display == "10ff":
            self._10ff_display(stdscr, time_left)

    def _handle_key(self, key):
        char = curses.keyname(key).decode()
        if char == "^R":
            self.restart()
        if key in (curses.KEY_BACKSPACE, 127):
            self.input = self.input[:-1]
        elif chr(key) == " ":
            self._finish_word_event()
        else:
            self.input += chr(key)

    @staticmethod
    def _setup_ncurses(stdscr):
        # hide cursor
        curses.curs_set(0)

        # setup colors for printing text to screen
        curses.use_default_colors()
        curses.init_pair(Game.CORRECT_COLOR, curses.COLOR_GREEN, 0)
        curses.init_pair(Game.INCORRECT_COLOR, curses.COLOR_RED, 0)

        # don't wait for user input when calling getch()/getkey()
        stdscr.nodelay(True)

        # allow 100ms sleep on getch()/getkey() avoiding busy-wait
        # early returns when key is pressed, meaning no input delay
        stdscr.timeout(100)

    def _game_loop(self, stdscr):
        self._setup_ncurses(stdscr)
        self._update_display(stdscr, self.game_time)

        started = False
        start = time.time()
        time_left = self.game_time
        while time_left > 0:
            if not started:
                start = time.time()

            key = stdscr.getch()
            new_time_left = int(round(self.game_time - (time.time() - start)))
            if key == -1:
                # only update display when necessary
                if time_left != new_time_left:
                    time_left = new_time_left
                    self._update_display(stdscr, time_left)

                continue

            time_left = new_time_left
            started = True
            self._handle_key(key)
            self._update_display(stdscr, time_left)

    def print_stats(self):
        """Print ACC/CPM/WPM to console"""
        correct = len(self.correct)
        total = correct + len(self.incorrect)
        accuracy = correct / total * 100
        print("ACC: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy))
        cpm = self.calculate_cpm(self.game_time)
        print("CPM: {:d}".format(cpm))
        wpm = self.calculate_wpm(self.game_time)
        print("WPM: {:d}".format(wpm))

    def restart(self):
        """
        Reset the Game class, effective starting a new game
        with new words, but based on same configuration.
        """
        self.input = ""
        self.correct = []
        self.incorrect = []
        self.typed = []
        self.next_words = [self._get_word() for _ in range(QUEUE_SIZE)]

        if self.display == "10ff":
            self.offset = 0
            self.current_line = []
            self.next_line = []

        self.play()

    def play(self):
        """Start typing game and print results to terminal"""
        curses.wrapper(self._game_loop)
        self.print_stats()


def main():
    """Parse arguments and start game based thereof"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        description=textwrap.dedent(
            """\
            Start a minimal 10fastfingers-like typing game on the command line.

            Keybinds:
                CTRL+R: restart
                CTRL+C: exit
            """
        ),
    )
    ## replace this with the select-difficulty + language
    parser.add_argument(
        "-v",
        "--vocab",
        type=str,
        metavar="vocab-file-path",
        default=VOCAB_PATH,
        help="path to newline separated vocab file",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-t",
        "--game_time",
        type=int,
        metavar="gametime-seconds",
        default=60,
        help="duration in seconds of the typing game",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-min",
        "--min_length",
        type=int,
        metavar="min-word-length",
        default=1,
        help="minimum word length",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-max",
        "--max_length",
        type=int,
        metavar="max-word-length",
        default=100,
        help="maximum word length",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-w",
        "--words",
        type=int,
        metavar="words-to-read",
        default=200,
        help="the amount of words to read from vocab - higher increases difficulty",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-a",
        "--advanced",
        action="store_const",
        const=1000,
        dest="words",
        help="use 1000 most common words (corresponds to 10ff advanced mode)",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-d",
        "--display",
        type=str,
        metavar="display",
        default="10ff",
        help="how to display words to type '10ff' or 'progressive'",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-m",
        "--mode",
        type=str,
        metavar="mode-selection",
        default="word",
        help="selecting which mode you wish to play the game in",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    game = Game(args)
    try:
        game.play()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

If anyone can give me advice on how to fix this that would help. Not sure if its the way I used pyinstaller or if its a problem with how I run a script within the first python file, and dependencies might not be implemented properly. Running the file give me the following: [image: Output of the exe file]

Comment: I think there are some missing files, this is often an issue with pyinstaller. Could you please run the *.exe from a cmd-line so that a possible error message will stay visible and will not disappear together with its temporary window

Comment: Thank you flipSTAR for the comment, I was able to find the issue and fix the problems I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a problem with directories. Pyinstaller put the executable file in it's own directory, where it couldn't import from the rest of my python files. I fixed it by dragging the executable into the directory with the rest of my python scripts. This is more of a temporary solution, as the executable has to be in the same directory as the other python files until I fix the import statements.